# Listening port for deployment, nodejs docker

Tags: node.js, docker, express, heroku, deployment

I have a simple node.js - express app and I set the listening port to 3000.
On my Dockerfile I expose port 3000 and run the container using `-p 3000:3000`.

I want to deploy my app on Heroku using my docker image, what is the proper way of doing it?

I am aware that in these cases we use `process.env` or specify a global variable in a `.env` file.

I list below my Dockerfile.

```
FROM node:10-alpine as builder

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

RUN apk --no-cache add python make g++

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

FROM node:10-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=builder node_modules node_modules

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "start:prod" ]
```

What is the proper way of approaching the problem?
Plus any suggestions for improving my Dockerfile are more than welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying a web application on Heroku they will tell you which port is free through an env variable. You have to bind that port in your source code.
In your Dockerfile remove `EXPOSE 3000` since you cannot open a custom port.

In your source code you will have to write something like `const port = process.env.PORT || 3000`.
So when you are executing your program locally and you don't have the env var `$PORT` set it will open the port 3000. On Heroku it will open the port on what is specified in `$PORT`.

---

A common hurdle when deploying on Heroku is that your URLs are no longer working. When running locally you might have the URL: `http://localhost:3000/` but on Heroku you have: `https://my-app.herokuapp.com/`.
http**s** can cause a bit of headache since you might have been working with http the whole time. Furthermore if you hardcoded the port at the end of the hostname it is going to cause some problems. Heroku automatically translates a hostname into an ip-address + port.

---

You can read here about deploying on Docker here:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/build-docker-images-heroku-yml

When you've made sure that your code is Heroku compatible you can start doing the Heroku Docker deployment. The article is very thorough and I believe it is better if you read them than me just copy pasting what it says there.